# The composer is installing different module versions than the required one

Tags: magento2, composer

On a Magento 2 branch, when I am running the composer will get different module versions than the required one. Let's say for the `Magento_Store` module I do need the 2.0.0 version, but the composer is installing the 2.1.0 version.

So after a succesful install when I am trying to access the website, I am getting error messages for both `schema_version` and `data_version` for lot's of modules.

Example:

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Store schema: current version - 2.1.0, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Store data: current version - 2.1.0, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Directory schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Directory data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
```

And the list is very long! Only part of it has been copied above.

Until now, I was trying to modify the version number in the `setup_module` table from database, but no luck. Before that, I was running the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command and also cleared the cache but I had the feeling I'm in a loop and always got back to the same error list. So, I guess my aproach was wrong.

Is there a solution to set up the right way the composer in order to avoid in future such problems? Or what should be the direction to aproach?

Answer (score 1):

composer install latest available version, that compatible with all your requirements.

You can manually add required version in your composer.json
"magento/module-store": "100.1" (it's for magento 2.1.*)

Comment: You mean in vendor/magento/composer/composer.json ?

Comment: No, composer.json file in magento root directory.

Comment: I have defined the required versions for modules in the composer.json but it is still installing the latest available versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the right requirements in composer.json (As stated by Alex before) and make sure to update the composer.lock by executing `composer update magento/module-store` to update the data for the omitted module or `composer update` to update all modules according to the requirements in composer.json.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ji8no1 this way is okay?

Comment: @GrávujMiklósHenrich that would make sure only version 2.0.0 would be used for these modules.
Don't forget to use `composer update magento/module-store magento/module-directory` after you edited the composer.json